# which ide is use for create and debug a apache cordova PLUGIN

Tags: cordova, plugins, ide

I'm going to develop an Apache Cordova Plugin.

Which IDE is the best,i need to develop a plugin for apache cordova but i do not if correct my source...

Comment: the question is very helpfull for developer that beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To develop the javascript part of your plugin you can always use the IDE you usually use for cordova development (e.g. [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)). Depending on which platforms you want to support with your plugin you will need one or more of the following IDEs:

- [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) to develop/run the Android platform (Java)
- [XCode](https://itunes.apple.com/at/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) to develop/run the iOS platform (Objective-C)

To get started I suggest to clone a simple existing plugin and rename it, remove all code you don't need, etc. so it fits your needs. Then you can add the local plugin to your project:

```
 cordova plugin add <path to your local plugin>
```

Then you open the native IDE (e.g. Android Studio) and import the native project located in `platfroms/android`. Then you can start to edit the `.java` files of your plugin and run it on a device via the IDE. When you're done don't forget to copy back your changes to your plugin folder otherwise the changes will be lost if you remove the platform.